# Разделить словарь на несколько по шаблону

Tags: python

Доброго времени суток.

Есть словарь вида:`{"id1": "Aaa", "id2": "Bbb"}`.

Как его распарсить в n-ое кол-во словарей по принципу: 
`{"name": "id1", "value": "Aaa"}, {"name": "id2", "value": "Bbb"}`

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [56]: [{'name':key, 'value':val} for key,val in d.items()]
Out[56]: [{'name': 'id1', 'value': 'Aaa'}, {'name': 'id2', 'value': 'Bbb'}]
```

или

```
In [55]: [dict(name=key, value=val) for key,val in d.items()]
Out[55]: [{'name': 'id1', 'value': 'Aaa'}, {'name': 'id2', 'value': 'Bbb'}]
```

Comment: А будет разница в скорости между Вашим и моим ответом при большом словаре на входе?

Comment: @IgorLavrynenko, я думаю они не будут сильно отличаться по скорости...

Comment: Я все время использую способ из ответа, а тут подумал, может смогу что-то выиграть используя Ваш вариант

Answer (score 1):

Или так:

```
>>> a = {"id1": "Aaa", "id2": "Bbb"}
>>> print([{'name': i, 'value': a[i]} for i in a])
[{'value': 'Aaa', 'name': 'id1'}, {'value': 'Bbb', 'name': 'id2'}]
```